# I try to count row and get data at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT  * , 
       count(*) as num_row , 
       tbl_posts.id AS post_id, 
       tbl_posts.public_id AS post_public_id 
FROM  tbl_posts  
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.id = tbl_posts.user_id 
WHERE slug= "wrong slug" AND 
      tbl_posts.public_id = "wrong id" 
GROUP BY post_id
```

I try to count row and get data at the same time, it works well if the 
 WHERE condition is right but when the condition is wrong COUNT function not show '0', why and how to solve this?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: you need to give aliases or the tables??

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense (`select *` with `group by`).  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: When your query includes multiple tables you need to prefix each column with the table name an alias. Otherwise, it becomes quite complicated for anyone but you to understand where each column comes from.